# I am unable to make an SQL query in Java

Tags: java, sql

My code is-

```
package textmessenger;
import java.sql.*;


public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
        String con = "jdbc:mysql://SQL09.FREEMYSQL.NET:3306/a5189576";
        Connection connection = null;

        Statement statement = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;
        int updateQuery = 0;

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(con, "user", "pwd");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String QueryString = "select * from names";
            rs = statement.executeQuery(QueryString);
            System.out.println("Executed");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this program, I get "Error" in the output. Where am I going wrong?
I have tried the SQL editor in NetBeans and it works perfectly fine there.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Print the exception (`ex.printStackTrace()`), you're hiding the actual error report with that println.

Comment: If you didn't ignore the exception/stacktrace and simply print "error", you'd know what the problem is :)

Comment: Your code is _explicitly_ ignoring error messages.  You'll want to fix that.  Error messages contain useful information.

Comment: Output-
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at textmessenger.Main.main(Main.java:29)`

Comment: Im sorry, but I'm new to Java programming

Comment: And there you go. You don't have the MySQL JDBC driver in your classpath. Did you download it and include it in your project? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: No I didn't include it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stacktrace you've now posted, You need to download the MySQL JDBC driver and include it in your project:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: how do I set it up in my project?

Comment: On the left in the project view you'll see "Libraries" right under "Source Packages" in your project. Right click on it, choose "add JAR/Folder" and add the Jar file from the download.